# What does \u003C mean?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at twitter's javascript file, and I see this in the templates hash:

```
Browse Interests{{/i}}\u003C/a\u003E\n        \u003C/li\u003E\n  {{#logged_in}}\n
```

What do those codes represent?

Comment: It’s [a Unicode character escape sequence](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode).

Answer (score 216, accepted):

It's a unicode character. In this case `\u003C` and `\u003E` mean :

> U+003C    <   Less-than sign
>
> U+003E    >   Greater-than sign

See a list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)

Answer (score 17):

That is a unicode character code that, when parsed by JavaScript as a string, is converted into its corresponding character (JavaScript automatically converts any occurrences of `\uXXXX` into the corresponding Unicode character). For example, your example would be:

```
Browse Interests{{/i}}</a>\n        </li>\n  {{#logged_in}}\n
```

As you can see, `\u003C` changes into `<` (less-than sign) and `\u003E` changes into `>` (greater-than sign).

In addition to the link posted by Raynos, [this page from the Unicode website](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) lists a lot of characters (so many that they decided to annoyingly group them) and [this page](http://www.unicode.org/charts/charindex.html) has a (kind of) nice index.

Answer (score 10):

It is a unicode char  \u003C = `<`

Answer (score 3):

Those are unicode escapes. The general unicode escapes looks like `\uxxxx` where `xxxx` are the hexadecimal digits of the ASCI characters. They are used mainly to insert special characters inside a javascript string.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript

```
unescape("\u003c")
```

to decode the unicode

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape

Although unescape() is not strictly deprecated (as in "removed from the Web standards")

Comment: No, absolutely not.

Comment: My bad. made some edits @Bergi

Answer (score 0):

Unicode all starts with \u e.g. \u0001