# <all_urls> get changed into \u003Call_urls> when uploading to the Chrome store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have an extension that works well on my local, the manifest has those configuration:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [ "js/tabCapture.js", "js/main.js" ],
    "persistent": false
},
"permissions": [ "desktopCapture", "tabs", "activeTab", "<all_urls>", "identity" ],
```

However, when uploading to Chrome store (successfully), I tried installing it but it didn't work any more. I checked the Extension tab and see no background page for my extension. Upon further investigation, I tried loading the extension folder and the `manifest.json` file of the downloaded extension is as follow:

```
   "background": {
      "persistent": false,
      "scripts": [ "js/tabCapture.js", "js/main.js" ]
   },
   "permissions": [ "desktopCapture", "tabs", "activeTab", "\u003Call_urls>", "identity" ],
```

As you see, `"<all_urls>"` has been turned into `"\u003Call_urls>"`. Why is it happening, anyone has the same problem?

Comment: Both are same as `\u003C` is unicode for `<`. It shouldn't change on upload so I guess there's something wrong in the way you do it. Also note, if your page has file:// URL you need to enable the corresponding checkbox in chrome://extensions details page (it's auto-enabled only for local unpacked extensions).

Comment: Thanks, somehow it works now. I noticed my app didn't work right after installation, but needed to restart Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Special meaning characters escaping.
Check [What does \u003C mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858494/what-does-u003c-mean)
If string value can be confused with command the safest way is to encode the character and then to decode it or let it be automatically decoded.

Like < or > or " or ' (&_lt; or &_gt; or &_quot; or &_apos; but with removed underscores) in the html/xml context, when text should be treated as text and not as a tag. [Wikipedia - Character encodings in HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#XML_character_references)